# Printing files that share the exact content

Tags: python, python-itertools, hashlib, listdir

My directories has hundreds of files some that have different names but duplicate contents. I've grouped the files in an array and perform follow operations:

```
import os 
import itertools
import hashlib 
directory = os.listdir(input())
  for collection1, collection2 in itertools.combinations (directory, 2): 

    def check(data):
      data_check = hashlib.md5()
      data_check.update(open(data).read())
      return data_check.hexdigest()

    def match_check(c1, c2):
      return check(c1) == check(c2) 

match_check(collection1,collection2)
```

Comment: There's no question here. On SO,  you need to not only provide a minimal example, but also the discrepancy between what you expect, and what your minimal example produces.

Comment: OK.  What's your question?

Comment: My example was incomplete, my  expectation from the code is to print the matches of files that have the exact same conten. t

Answer (score 0):

You could instead use a `dict`, using the `MD5` as a key. For example something like:

```
files = {}

# In the loop:
  sum = hashlib.md5(open(data].read())
  if sum in files:
    # A file already exists for this MD5 sum, append the file
    files[sum].append(data)
  else:
    # First file with this MD5 sum
    files[sum] = [data]
```

You can then list the values of the `dict` that share the same index. For example:

```
for sum, l in files.values():
  if l.length() > 1:
    # More than one file with the same MD5 file
    # Do something
```